# triggering jquery .animate after user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to figure out why this script is not working.
What I have is a `div` hiding behind another `div` and need it to animate up after a user scrolls on the page.

This is my script:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){   
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (top > 50) {        
      $('#merch').animate({ bottom: 200 }, 
        {duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});         
        }        
    else {
      $('#merch').slideDown();
    }        
});
```

Comment: Hey man, flick your html please, I will take a look! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scroll(function(){   
var top = $(document).scrollTop();

if (top > 50) {        
  $('#merch').animate({ top: '500px' }, 
    {duration: 1000});        
    }        
else {
  $('#merch').slideDown();
}        });
```

1. I'm getting an error that on the easing value you are passing, might want to look into that.
2. animate values need to be in quotes with a px value
3. make sure merch has 'position: relative;' in the CSS. without it, the jQuery can't move the element

Answer (score -1):

There is no onscrollcomplete function, but you can monkey wrench one together:

```
var int;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout(int);
    int = setTimeout(function(){
        //animation here
    }, 300);
});
```

Wait 300ms then fire the animation function to pull the div to the top of the page.